# atom package that lets me view opened files

Tags: text-editor, atom.io

I use a windows machine. Earlier I have used the tree-view-opened-files package to be able to keep track of the files I've opened.

This is supposed to show up in the tree view sidebar, but it doesn't.

Can anyone recommend a reliable package.

The version of atom being used: 1.17.2

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a Mac and I use Atom often. The Treeview package works fine and shows directory and files in left sidebar. Maybe the sidebar is hidden if Treeview doesn't appear to be working. The Treeview web page tells the keystrokes to use to make things visible.

Answer (score 0):

I also confirm that [tree-view](https://atom.io/packages/tree-view) works fine in Atom 1.18.0 on Windows. Make sure you are familiar with the hotkeys and have them enabled:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want an [electron-based](https://electron.atom.io/) IDE, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has similar functionality [out of the box](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_files-folders-projects) and just seems more responsive that Atom.